# Can someone tell me the name of this piece?

Tags: identify-this-song, classical-music, guitar

I learned this tune a long while back and do not remember it's name or the entire piece. I've recorded what I remembered and was hoping if someone knows it and can tell me it's name.
You can listen to my recording here: https://clyp.it/5le1asu0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a study from Ferdinando Carulli, from opus 241 (Ecole de Guitare). 
Don't know exactly where it appears in the original, but you might find it [here](https://imslp.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_de_guitare%2C_Op.241_(Carulli%2C_Ferdinando)), if you're willing to do some searching.

And, fwiw, I find it a lovely piece. Delicate, simple, easy, without any frills. Just plain pretty, beautiful. I'm not a big Carulli fan, but he had his moments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! The piece is called `Andante`

Comment: @Brahadeesh Yes sorry, it's Andantino apparently. You can find the tab here: https://tabs.ultimate-guitar.com/tab/ferdinando-carulli/andantino-tabs-895722